# Multple Google Fonts in html doc

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-webfonts

I want to apply a google font to only specific css selectors or elements in my page.

I also want the same font in mutliple weights (Eg Roboto). Not controlled using the css attribute but actually using the separate font versions provided by google.

If possible id prefer not to have an external stylesheet.

Is this possible? I dont mind doing in a script tag if i have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a example and I've put the style in the html so you dont need a external stylesheet although I wouldn't recommend it

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&family=Rowdies&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  h2,
  h3,
  span {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
  
  h2 {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  h3 {
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  
  h1,
  p {
    font-family: 'Rowdies', cursive;
  }
</style>
<h1>h1 Rowdies</h1>
<h2>h2 Roboto font-weight 500</h2>
<h3>h3 Roboto font-weight 700</h3>
<p>p Rowdies</p>
<span>span Roboto</span>
```

> *I also want the same font in mutliple weights (Eg Roboto). Not controlled using the css attribute but actually using the separate font versions provided by google.*

Not a 100% sure if its possible or not but I see no reason why you can't just use the `font-weight` property

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I wasnt able to get the same result using the font weight property with roboto 900. Maybe im missing something Ill give it another look

Comment: You need to include all the weights you want to use see the first line of my code it says the following in the url `family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700` (generated by google fonts) so I am getting the 400,500,700 fontweight this also applies to italic

Comment: Thanks! That might be it

Comment: You're welcome glad I could help, can you accept my answer? :)